# How to write common function for two functions in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

I have a class in which their are two methods `handleChange(e)` and `cardClick(e)` and i want to sort an object array both of the functions.
My code is:

```
handleChange(e){
arr.sort(compare);
            function compare(a, b){
                if(a.population === 'unknown')
                    return 1;
                if(b.population === 'unknown')
                    return -1;
                if(parseInt(a.population) < parseInt(b.population))
                    return 1;
                else if(parseInt(a.population) > parseInt(b.population))
                    return -1;
                else
                    return 0;
            }
}
```

and

```
cardClick(e){
arr.sort(compare);
            function compare(a, b){
                if(a.population === 'unknown')
                    return 1;
                if(b.population === 'unknown')
                    return -1;
                if(parseInt(a.population) < parseInt(b.population))
                    return 1;
                else if(parseInt(a.population) > parseInt(b.population))
                    return -1;
                else
                    return 0;
            }
}
```

I have to write the compare function definition in both handleChange and cardClick. Is their any way so that i don't have to write it twice, and i can use it in both functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the function outside of the class and use it in both event handlers.

**Example**

```js
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a.population === "unknown") return 1;
  if (b.population === "unknown") return -1;
  if (parseInt(a.population) < parseInt(b.population)) return 1;
  else if (parseInt(a.population) > parseInt(b.population)) return -1;
  else return 0;
}

class App extends React.Component {
  handleChange = e => {
    arr.sort(compare);
    // ...
  };

  cardClick = e => {
    arr.sort(compare);
    // ...
  };

  render() {
    // ...
  }
}
```